# Imported struct method not working

Tags: oop, methods, struct, go

If I run the following code everything compiles and runs fine:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Point struct {
    x, y int
}

func (p *Point) init() bool {
    p.x = 5
    p.y = 10
    return true
}

func main() {
    point := Point{}
    point.init()
    fmt.Println(point)
}
```

But when I move the `Point struct` to a package in the `$GOPATH` directory then I get the following error: `point.init undefined (cannot refer to unexported field or method class.(*Point)."".init)`

Can anyone explain to me why this happens?

Once I put the `Point struct` in a package called `class` the code looks as follows (the error is on the 8th line where I call the `init` method):

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "class"

func main() {
    point := class.Point{}
    point.init()
    fmt.Println(point)
}
```

Comment: It's idiomatic to write a function `NewPoint` to construct a point from various parameters instead of calling `Init` afterwards.

Comment: True but I'm using this with the RPC package and it only allows to register one object so I had to put the init as a method

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rename **init**() to **Init**() should work!
Basically, all the things(function, method, struct, variable) that not start with an Unicode upper case letter will just visible inside their package!

You need to read more from the language spec here:
http://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers

Relevant bit:

> An identifier may be exported to permit access to it from another package. An identifier is exported if both:
>
> 1. the first character of the identifier's name is a Unicode upper case letter (Unicode class "Lu"); and
> 2. the identifier is declared in the package block or it is a field name or method name.
>    All other identifiers are not exported.

Comment: Cool that's a much better source than mine, but you should always include the relevant quote from the source because links can become invalid

Answer (score 5):

Only functions/methods that have the first letter of their name capitalized are exported

http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#commentary

> Every exported (capitalized) name in a program...

When I changed `init` to `Init` everything worked.